# Flask passing global variable

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to passing the flask app context with some global variable to the nested api context.

```
run.py <= Start the flask application via app.run()
    app/
       __init__.py
       api/
          __init__.py
          controllers.py
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from app.api.controllers import api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')

main_dict = {"a":"info1", "b":"info2}
```

**app/api/controllers.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify
from app import app, main_dict

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/')
def test():
    return jsonify({"status":"OK"})
```

It throws the following error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a circular dependency.

`app` wants to import `app.api.controllers`, but that wants to import from `app`. What you should do to fix it, is to create a new module containing `main_dict` and import that in both `app` and `app.api.controllers`:

```
# app/__init__.py
from .main_dict import main_dict
from .api.controllers import api

# app/main_dict.py
main_dict = {'a': 'A'}

# app/api/__init__.py

# app/api/controllers.py
from flask import current_app as app
from ..main_dict import main_dict
```

if you need access to the app outside of `app/__init__.py`, the recommended way to get at it is to use `from flask import current_app`

Comment: Another solution would be to just move the assignment of `main_dict` above `from app.api.controllers import api`.

Comment: @Blender Yes, true. But I've always been taught it was generally considered poor form to put imports anywhere except at the top, above your code?

Comment: @NetBlocker Sorry, see my edit. (Python modules are referenced by their name without the `.py` extension)