# Flask app, global variable over multiple files

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to share a variable I defined in my main function with a flask app which is imported from another file. First I tried to solve it via a classic `global` variable which did not bring me any further, until I stumbled over the concept of [flask.g and the app context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#:%7E:text=Storing%20Data&text=Flask%20provides%20the%20g%20object,being%20global%20within%20a%20context).

So I tried the following: I have two files in the same directory, a `main.py`:

```py
# main.py

import app
from flask import g

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app.app_context():
        g.value = "Hello World"
    
    app.app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

and a `app.py`:

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask, g

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/helloworld')
def send_response():
    return g.value
```

However, when I request at http://localhost:5000/helloworld I get

```
AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'value'
```

So it seems that setting the value `g.value` in one file is not reflected in the app.
I'm a beginner in Flask and it is very likely I did not get the concept right.
Similar questions did not get me any answer I could use to fix the issue:
[Flask passing global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226531/flask-passing-global-variable), [python-How to set global variables in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309042/python-how-to-set-global-variables-in-flask), [Preserving global state in a flask application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277280/preserving-global-state-in-a-flask-application)

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regular Python module-level variable.

```
# app.py

g = "Example"

@app.route("/example")
def example_endpoint():
    return g
```

```
# main.py

import app

app.g = "Hello"
```

Quoting the same page you linked:

> The application context is created and destroyed as necessary. When a Flask application begins handling a request, it pushes an application context and a request context. When the request ends it pops the request context then the application context. Typically, an application context will have the same lifetime as a request.

So your setting `flask.g` outside of a request context (in your `main.py`) doesn't carry your value to anywhere.

Comment: Is the file `main.py` necessary here?